# angularjs datepicker not working

Tags: angularjs

I'm using `Angularjs`. In that I'm using jquery for datepicker; but when I'm passing the selected date value it is not fetching the selected value. I need a solution for this problem.

Find below my code:

Markup

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Project Startdate</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <!--   <input type="text" name="prjstartdate" id="prjstartdate" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.user.prjstartdate" required />-->
        <div class="container" id="sandbox-container">
            <div class="input-daterange input-group" id="datepicker" name="prjstartdate" id="prjstartdate" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.prjstartdate">
                <input type="text" name="prjstartdate" id="prjstartdate" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.prjstartdate" required />
            </div>
        </div>
        <span ng-show="form.password.$dirty && form.password.$error.required" class="help-block">Password is required</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Function:

```
function MyCntrlsave($scope,$http) {

    $scope.savedetails = function() {
        var vm = this;
        var projectname = $scope.vm.prjname;
        var cilentname = $scope.vm.clientname;
        var clientstatus = $scope.vm.prjsta;
        var prjstartdate = $scope.vm.prjstartdate;
        var prjenddate = $scope.vm.prjenddate;
        var prjurl = $scope.vm.prjurl;
        alert("projectname"+projectname);
        alert("cilentname"+cilentname);
        alert("prjstartdate"+prjstartdate);
    };

};
```

Answer (score 4):

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="prjstartdate" id="prjstartdate" class="form-control" ng-model="prjstartdate" required jqdatepicker/>
```

In controller

```
var prjstartdate = $scope.prjstartdate
```

Use jQuery UI and add a directive

```
datePicker.directive('jqdatepicker', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
     link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
        element.datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
            onSelect: function (date) {
                scope.prjstartdate = date;
                scope.$apply();
            }
        });
    }
}; 
});
```

[Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/winsandymyint/TAeNF/812/)